# need to redirect all files from http to https plus need to remove .php extention from all files except few and also want to rewrite the urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteOptions inherit
DirectoryIndex index.php
#IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$   about-us.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^domain-web-hosting/?$   domain-web-hosting.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^graphic-creative-design/?$   graphic-creative-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^logo-design/?$   logo-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^email-design/?$   email-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^banner-design/?$   banner-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^website-design/?$   website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^static-website-design/?$   static-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^dynamic-website-design/?$   dynamic-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^corporate-website-design/?$   corporate-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ecommerce-website-design/?$   ecommerce-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms-website-design/?$  cms-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^responsive-website-design/?$  responsive-website-design.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^website-maintenance/?$  website-maintenance.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^website-redesigning/?$  website-redesigning.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^website-development/?$  website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ecommerce-website-development/?$  ecommerce-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^opencart-website-development/?$  opencart-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^prestashop-website-development/?$  prestashop-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^magento-website-development/?$  magento-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms-website-development/?$  cms-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^joomla-website-development/?$  joomla-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress-website-development/?$  wordpress-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^custom-website-development/?$  custom-website-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^application-development/?$  application-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^web-application-development/?$  web-application-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile-application-development/?$  mobile-application-development.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^internet-marketing/?$  internet-marketing.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^search-engine-optimization/?$  search-engine-optimization.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ppc-management/?$  ppc-management.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^content-writing/?$  content-writing.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$  portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^web-design-plans/?$  web-design-plans.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^seo-plans/?$  seo-plans.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^static-website-portfolio/?$  static-website-portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms-website-portfolio/?$  cms-website-portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ecommerce-website-portfolio/?$  ecommerce-website-portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^custom-web-development-portfolio/?$  custom-web-development-portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^logo-portfolio/?$  logo-portfolio.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^web-design-templates/?$  web-design-templates.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^faq/?$  faq.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^testimonials/?$  testimonials.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^partner-with-us/?$  partner-with-us.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$  contact-us.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/?$  privacy-policy.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions/?$  terms-and-conditions.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^disclaimer/?$  disclaimer.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^payment/?$  payment-options.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^package-form/?$  package-form.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^business-website-packages/?$  business-website-packages.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ecommerce-website-packages/?$  ecommerce-website-packages.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$  sitemap.php  [NC]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteindia.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.websiteindia.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web-design-templates
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/layouts
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.websiteindia.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

please see this my .htaccess file. Issue i have is .php files are also visible which i want to get redirected to non .php files.. except few files namely captcha.php and process.php. and also want to redirect all pages from https to non https i.e. http://www.websiteindia.net/web-design-templates as it has an iframe any help will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/? $1.php [L]
```

No need to add anything else. htaccess needs only this code and check if all your conditions are satisfied.